# ArgumentError in Users::Registrations#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

> I am making a user-sign_up interface by using devise gem

Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set `default_url_options[:host]`, or set :only_path to true

```
 <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
 <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set host variable to the application url. Something like this in environment.rb file

config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: application url' }